# Sharing data between two independent Windows applications in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two applications that use my clients database(s), but have no mutual dependency. The problem is that I need to make an application for configuration in which the administrator could set the parameters. For instance which database to which the two applications connect and some other parameters, mostly string and numerical. These parameters must affect both applications.

The first solution that I thought of is to make a configuration file in which I could store the data and the applications would read that file on startup. The problem with this approach is that it is not very safe (even if I encrypt the data in the file).

Is there a way to send data from one application to the other, assuming that each application is created as an individual project?

Comment: Why is it not safe to encrypt a file?

Comment: Good question, a good salted encryption should be more secured than socket communication.

Comment: My client simply said he wouldn't like to have a file that contains connection string (with user name and password for the database) and similar data. I'm just trying to oblige, the file approach is my backup plan if I don't find a more direct way

Comment: If you're creating an application in C#, it's not much better to use a string in the application. A string in the application can easily be extracted. So you're only left with having the user enter the connection string *every time*, is that what your client wants?

Comment: Your problem is that your client is using unsafe practices.  And now is trying to push his problem onto you.  You'll need to resist that, you cannot possibly win.  Never handle passwords in your code.  Tell him that he needs to start using SSPI.

Comment: I doubt it, since one of the applications is intended for workers on cash registers (which are not so educated in computer science), so it should be as simple as possible. I'll talk to my client again, because in order to apply these changes, all applications must be running, and they want to change the data in the configuration and then it should be applied to each application, whenever it (they) are started

Comment: So you're saying they're likely to decipher a configuration file, but not proficient enough in choosing "open file" in ildasm?

Comment: To quote msdn; [*Never hard-code a password within your source code. Hard coded passwords can be retrieved from an assembly using the Ildasm.exe (MSIL Disassembler) tool, a hex editor, or by simply opening up the assembly in a text editor like notepad.exe.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.aspx)

Comment: I'm just listing the requirements I got from my client, I'm not assuming anyones level of knowledge. As for using passwords, I'm getting it from app.config. Is that safer, or is it the same risk as hard coded?

Comment: Aren't your requirements also that the connection string should not easily be found? In that case it's kind of up to you as a developer to show your client the fallacies in the requested solution.

Comment: Like I said, my initial idea was the one with the configuration file. They asked me to see if there is another way, but I might talk them into using that approach. Also, I'm not that experienced, so I don't know the safety protocols that could be applied

Comment: @NDraskovic: Don't forget, as Hans noted, you should start using SSPI as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)

You can use it as a file, and access from different executables.

Build your own class for interfacing with it.

Tutorials:

[Programming Memory-Mapped Files with the .NET Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138290/Programming-Memory-Mapped-Files-with-the-NET-Frame)

[Working with memory mapped files in .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

or you can even use named pipe :
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060404.asp
Or make communication with socket.

You have a plenty of solution.
If you need more details, feel free to ask.

Best regards,
Sylvain.